# Calling windows form method from class file

Tags: c#

I want to force closing a windows application by calling `application.exit()` on the class file. But it only hide the application, the .exe still running on the task manager.

I want to ask is there a way to fully terminate the windows application that can call on the class file? I can't call the windows form method from class file to perform `this.close()`.

Comment: What do you mean by "that can call on the class file"? It's unclear what your situation is. Do you have a reference to the form? Do you have any other threads running? A short but complete program demonstrating your problem would be very handy.

Comment: Sounds like you have background threads still running.

Comment: There are threads running. What i mean is for example i have a class name call CommManager and a windows form application called MainForm. In that CommManager i want to use a command to force closing the windows application. If i call the application.exit() on the CommManager, it won't terminate the whole application. Is there anyway to fully terminate it including the threads that running in the MainForm which can only calling in the CommManager class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Application.Exit` only closes the Winforms event loops, i.e. only the so called *GUI thread* is terminated.

You could call the `Environment.Exit` method to terminate the whole process. But if you have other threads running you should take care to terminate them properly, usually by sending them some message (but this depends entirely on your architecture).